# Shared object file not generated when using gSOAP to create webservices

Tags: apache, gsoap, .so

I am using gSOAP to create webservices from C code, following [this website](https://www.genivia.com/doc/apache/html/index.html). I use these commands:

```
soapcpp2 -c -SL -wx calc.h
bin/apxs -a -c calcserver.c soapC.c soapServer.c stdsoap2.c
chmod 755 .libs/calcserver.so
```

The first two commands successfully execute and generate these files:

```
calcserver.o
calcserver.lo
calcserver.slo
calcserver.a
```

But the file `calcserver.so` does not seem to be generated.

1. What is the reason that the `.so` file isn't being generated?
2. Is there any way to create `.so` files from the files generated above?

Answer (score 0):

The `calcserver.so` file is placed in the `.libs` directory under your current directory. The `.libs` directory should contain `calcserver.so` and other files:

```
calcserver.a
calcserver.la
calcserver.lai
calcserver.o
calcserver.so
soapC.o
soapServer.o
stdsoap2.o
```

To deploy the Apache module, edit `httpd.conf` (which is usually found in 1/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`or if you locally installed`httpd`in`/home/username/apachegsoap`then you will find it in`/home/username/apachegsoap/conf`) and add the following entry:

```
<IfModule mod_gsoap.c>
 <Location /soap>
  SetHandler gsoap_handler
  SOAPLibrary /home/username/apachegsoap/.libs/calcserver.so
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Location>
</IfModule>
```

where `/home/username/apachegsoap` should be modified to the path of your `.libs` directory.

For details, see the official gSOAP Apache module documentation at https://www.genivia.com/doc/apache/html/index.html

Comment: i agree what you said,but in ./libs directory all above mentioned files are generating except the calcserver.so file,my problem is that why calcserver.so file is not generating?